# How to use source maps in Chrome dev tools to analyze Performance profiling recording

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

I have a performance profiling recordings from customer where I can see obfuscated method names.

I have both the obfuscated JS file and source maps for it.

I would like to see unobfuscated method names after opening the performance recording in Chrome dev tools.

Unfortunately I don't know how to load source maps. Urls in the recording even point to a domain.

Any idea how to tell Chrome to use specific source maps from drive?

Answer (score 0):

When you receive profile recording from customer there is unfortunately no known way how to make source maps work and how to see what exact functions are slow.

But I managed to figure it out how to use sourcemaps when profiling production code on my machine:

1. Be sure to have source maps enabled in dev console settings: Settings → Enable JavaScript source maps.
2. Get the source map to your machine
3. In Chrome open dev tools → source → open the minified file → right click → Add source maps...
4. Enter URL to file on your machine as such: `file:///Users/martin.nuc/Downloads/main-4f1117b5938baf87eec6.js.map`

> After refresh you have to add the source map manually again.

> Don’t use Pretty-print - “Add source maps” is not available there